# Where the Iterator interface implemented in Java prior to jdk7

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I'd checked the `java` source API of `jdk6` and `jdk7`. In there in `jdk7` `ArrayList` class have an private inner class which implements the `Iterator` interface but in `jdk6` there's no such thing, even I don't found the `iterator()` which will return the instance of `Iterator`.

Can anybody tell me prior to `jdk7` how the instance of `Iterator` is received and where the methods of `Iterator` interface are implemented?

Comment: Post the v7 and v6 ArrayList.iterator() methods so we can have a peek at what you found.

Comment: @ChuckFricano: I'm sorry but what you are asking me for?
  I'm just asking `where` can I find the implemented class of `Iterator` prior to `java7`. Because in `java7` `ArrayList` class has an private inner class which implements the `Iterator` interface but not in `java6`

Comment: Hello Mohammad.  I'm asking you to post the 3 or 4 lines of Java source code from where you are looking at the two versions of the ArrayList.iterator() method.  They should be the same but it sounds like you are seeing two different implementations.  I want to see what you are seeing.

Comment: Ah. I see by the answers you must have been looking at the JavaDoc. Never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 6, the iterator implementation class is a private inner class in [`AbstractList`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/AbstractList.java.html) class (the superclass of `ArrayList`).  Search for the identifier `Itr` in the source code.

---

Why are the Java 6 and Java 7 versions different?  Well, this comment in the Java 7 source code is a big clue:

```
 777       /**
 778        * An optimized version of AbstractList.Itr
 779        */
 780       private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
```

I'll leave it to the reader to research the nature of those optimizations.  (Read the source Luke!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me if `AbstractList` has the implemented class of `Iterator` than why in java7 `ArrayList` also have the implemented class of `Iterator`? Is there any need for this?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal - I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: As the comment says, `ArrayList` rolls its own, more optimized implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc for ArrayList in JDK 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) shows `iterator()` as something inherited from [`AbstractList`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/AbstractList.java.html).